# Parsing two input files and comparing line existence

Tags: sed, text-editing, parsing

I need to take two text files and check to see if a line that exists in File A doesn't exist anywhere in File B.

Each line in File A that does not exist in File B should be copied to an output log.

A friend of mine suggested SED but I've never used it before, so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the lines are intended to be unique and order doesn't matter, so try this:

```
sort fileA > fileA.sort
sort fileB > fileB.sort
diff fileA.sort fileB.sort | sed -n "/^</{s/< //;p}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Lines that only exist in fileA:

```
comm -23 <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB) > output.txt
```

All lines unique to fileA will be saved in the file `output.txt`.

Comment: Process substitution using the `<(...)` notation is an elegant solution.  I thought about suggesting that form myself but it's only in bash, not the other shells, and it wasn't clear what shell the OP was using.